# How to render different terrain with different texture by using heightmap in directx12?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, directx-12

[image: terrain demo]

```
bool TerrainDemo::ReadRawFile(std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filePath.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::vector<BYTE> inData(inFile.tellg());
    inFile.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    inFile.read((char*)&inData[0], inData.size());
    inFile.close();

    m_heightInfos.resize(inData.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inData.size(); ++i)
    {
        m_heightInfos[i] = inData[i];
    }

    return true;
}


bool TerrainDemo::InitTerrain(float width, float height, UINT m, UINT n,     float scale)
{
    m_cellsPerRow = m;
    m_cellsPerCol = n;
    m_verticesPerRow = m + 1;
    m_verticesPerCol = n + 1;
    m_numsVertices = m_verticesPerRow*m_verticesPerCol;
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    m_heightScale = scale;

for (auto& item : m_heightInfos)
{
    item *= m_heightScale;
}

float oX = -width * 0.5f;
float oZ = height * 0.5f;
//每一格坐标变化
float dx = width / m;
float dz = height / n;

m_vertices.resize(m_numsVertices);


for (UINT i = 0; i < m_verticesPerCol; ++i)
{
    float tempZ = oZ - dz * i;
    for (UINT j = 0; j < m_verticesPerRow; ++j)
    {
        UINT index = m_verticesPerRow * i + j;
        m_vertices[index].Pos.x = oX + dx * j;
        m_vertices[index].Pos.y = m_heightInfos[index];
        m_vertices[index].Pos.z = tempZ;
        m_vertices[index].TexC = XMFLOAT2(dx*i, dx*j);                      
    }
}



UINT nIndices = m * n * 6;
m_indices.resize(nIndices);
UINT tmp = 0;
for (UINT i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (UINT j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
        m_indices[tmp] = i * m_verticesPerRow + j;
        m_indices[tmp + 1] = i * m_verticesPerRow + j + 1;
        m_indices[tmp + 2] = (i + 1) * m_verticesPerRow + j;

        XMFLOAT3 temp;
        ComputeNomal(m_vertices[m_indices[tmp]], m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 1]],
            m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 2]], temp);
        m_vertices[m_indices[tmp]].Normal = temp;
        m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 1]].Normal = temp;
        m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 2]].Normal = temp;


        m_indices[tmp + 3] = i * m_verticesPerRow + j + 1;
        m_indices[tmp + 4] = (i + 1) * m_verticesPerRow + j + 1;
        m_indices[tmp + 5] = (i + 1) * m_verticesPerRow + j;

        ComputeNomal(m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 3]], m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 4]],
            m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 5]], temp);
        m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 3]].Normal = temp;
        m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 4]].Normal = temp;
        m_vertices[m_indices[tmp + 5]].Normal = temp;

        tmp += 6;
    }


}

return true;
```

}

```
void TerrainDemo::ComputeNomal(Vertex& v1, Vertex& v2, Vertex& v3, XMFLOAT3& normal)
{
XMFLOAT3 f1(v2.Pos.x - v1.Pos.x, v2.Pos.y - v1.Pos.y, v2.Pos.z - v1.Pos.z);
XMFLOAT3 f2(v3.Pos.x - v1.Pos.x, v3.Pos.y - v1.Pos.y, v3.Pos.z - v1.Pos.z);
XMVECTOR vec1 = XMLoadFloat3(&f1);
XMVECTOR vec2 = XMLoadFloat3(&f2);
XMVECTOR temp = XMVector3Normalize(XMVector3Cross(vec1, vec2));
XMStoreFloat3(&normal, temp);
}
```

as the picture,I render a terrain by analyzing a heightmap，but only use one texture. Different height in the picture represent different terrain such as road,grass,water and so on. how to use different texture to render different terrain? Must I compute the vertices and indices of different parts of terrain?
some parts are irregular, and how to compute the index of them? Is it Ok to do this in shaders,and how to do?

Comment: If it is entirely determined by the height, then a simple option involves sampling from the appropriate texture in the pixel shader.

Comment: Yes,it is entirely determined by the height. Could you please give some sample code of the pixel shader，thank you.

Comment: In the simplest form something like `if(height < a) return groundTexture.Sample(sampler, uv); else if(height < b) return grassTexture.Sample(sampler, uv); else ...`. And then you can choose to interpolate on the boundaries.